# Show descrition text (WINAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I was wondering how I can show description text. By this I mean, for example if you hover over the Start button a small description will appear saying "Start". How are these invoked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [**Tooltip Controls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760250(VS.85).aspx)